# .gemrc file specification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I searched everywhere to find the `.gemrc` file specification but I haven't succeed.

Does anyone know where I can find it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

gem looks for a configuration file `.gemrc` in your home directory, although you can specify another file on the command-line if you wish (with the `--config-file` modifier).

There are three things you can specify in the configuration file:

- command-line arguments to be used every time gem runs
- command-line options for ’’RDoc’’ (used when generating documentation)
- `GEM_PATH` settings

More at [gem environment command doc](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-environment).

Comment: The doc for `.gemrc` has been moved to the [`gem environment` command doc](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_environment).

Comment: Doc has moved again: http://docs.seattlerb.org/rubygems/Gem/ConfigFile.html

Answer (score 10):

'Home' is a Linux/Mac term.  What is refers to is the folder where a user's settings appear.  You can find out where your settings directory is by doing the following:

**on Unix/Linux, open a terminal and type the following command:**

```
echo $HOME
```

**on Windows, open a command-prompt and type the following command:**

```
echo %USERPROFILE%
```

For me (in Windows 7), this is C:\Users[name].  However, looks like Ruby doesn't set up your .gemrc in that folder by default.  Instead, you have to create the file.  Open a text editor, copy the YAML style code you need ([documentation](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/11)), and save the file as .gemrc in your home directory (make sure you select all files, not '.txt').

These settings will only affect that individual user.  If it's your personal computer, however, you probably don't need to change the settings for all users.

Answer (score 9):

An updated gemrc specification is available at [RubyGems Guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/) (under '[gem environment](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_environment)'). Note that /etc/gemrc applies to all users, while ~/.gemrc applies to an individual.

If the key is a gem command (for example, `install:`), it specifies arguments to be used with that command.

Here are the other keys that can be specified:

```
:sources: A YAML array of remote gem repositories to install gems from
:verbose: Verbosity of the gem command.  false, true, and :really are the levels
:update_sources: Enable/disable automatic updating of repository metadata
:backtrace: Print backtrace when RubyGems encounters an error
:gempath: The paths in which to look for gems
```

Comment: From a quick try, it looks to me like the keys listed above must be prefixed with a `:` (as shown) while commands (such as `install`) must not be. This is consistent with the example given in the RubyGems Guides.

Comment: If you're like me, you failed to find the documentation for the gemrc. Here's a link to it: https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-environment

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers here at time of writing are wrong because the obnoxious website keeps changing. It is at this moment here:

https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-environment

Obviously you should expect it to change constantly at this point.